# devexpress gridview to export pdf issue

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I am new at Devexpress and need help
I am exporting to pdf but pdf colums not good need to autosize
how can I with code ?

here is my codes

```
private void navBarPdf_ElementClick(object sender, NavElementEventArgs e)
        {
            var save = new SaveFileDialog();            


            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                gridView1.ExportToPdf(save.FileName + ".pdf");


              


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just right click on the header of your gridview and click BestFit(all columns) and the export your pdf
this works for me

Best